# Git Cherry pick creates a diff in target

Tags: git, gitlab, git-flow, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

Context:
I have 2 target branches named R1 and R2 (Release 2).
I did changes using F1.1 and merged it to R1.
R1 was moved to Production.
R2 was created after R1 was released.
In a hurry, instead of creating a new branch, I continued in F1.1 and merged my changes to R2.

Now I want those changes to be tracked using another new branch. I tried to create a new Branch F1.2 and cherry-pick the recent changes in F1.1 into F1.2.

When I raised a pull request with R2 as target and F1.2 as the merging branch, It still showed the changes as a diff. I never reverted the recent changes in R2.

Any ideas what is happening here?

What I expected was, no diff in the R2 branch or maybe a conflict might occur. Neither of these happened. I want to understand this. Someone, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you pushed the changes to R2?

Comment: Yeah! I did @choroba

Comment: Where does F1.2 start?

Comment: From the release branch R1.

Comment: Please show the output of `gitk --all` or `git log --all --oneline --decorate --graph`.